# Swipe to Refresh only at a specific place?

Tags: android, google-maps, swiperefreshlayout

I have an Activity that has two components, one is a Scroll View and the other is a Fragment which contains Google Map (implemented API).
I would like to modify SwipeRefreshLayout to work only within the Scroll View. I don't want it to work while I use the Map.

Is there a way I can modify it?

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: Provide your layout please